# Calculate number of hours , minutes and seconds between two dates in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

Suppose we have to DateTime formatted date like this :

```
$started_at = '2016-07-05 12:29:16';
$ended_at = '2016-07-06 13:30:10';
```

Now I want to calculate number of hours , minutes and seconds of them like this :

```
15 hours and 50 minutes and 15 seconds
```

How Can I do that in simplest way in laravel and using [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
$t1 = Carbon::parse('2016-07-05 12:29:16');
$t2 = Carbon::parse('2016-07-04 13:30:10');
$diff = $t1->diff($t2);
```

This will give you

```
DateInterval {#727
     +"y": 0,
     +"m": 0,
     +"d": 0,
     +"h": 22,
     +"i": 59,
     +"s": 6,
     +"weekday": 0,
     +"weekday_behavior": 0,
     +"first_last_day_of": 0,
     +"invert": 1,
     +"days": 0,
     +"special_type": 0,
     +"special_amount": 0,
     +"have_weekday_relative": 0,
     +"have_special_relative": 0,
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

### How to calculate date different between two dates in Laravel

```
$date1 = new DateTime("2018-01-10 00:00:00");
$date2 = new DateTime("2019-05-18 01:23:45");
$difference = $date1->diff($date2);
$diffInSeconds = $difference->s; //45
$diffInMinutes = $difference->i; //23
$diffInHours   = $difference->h; //8
$diffInDays    = $difference->d; //21
$diffInMonths  = $difference->m; //4
$diffInYears   = $difference->y; //1
```